# In woocommerce show the check payment option when an order total is 0 dollars

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

On my wordpress, woocommerce  website I am trying to add something to the function.php of my theme that will enable the pay with check option if the order total is 0 dollars.

what I have so far:

```
function payment_gateway_enable_check( $available_gateways ) {
global $woocommerce;
if ( !isset( $available_gateways['check'] ) && $woocommerce->cart->total == 0 ) {
    set(  $available_gateways['check'] );
}
    return $available_gateways;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'payment_gateway_enable_check' );
```

Obviously set isn't correct, but I am not sure what to use in place of it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the total order is 0 there is no need of payment so woocommerce have `woocommerce_cart_needs_payment` which will give false when total is 0 so no payment methods are required.

Just fyi **cheque** is the name of the gateway not **check**

```
//Allow accepting payments if total is 0 (free order)
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_needs_payment', '__return_true' );

//Unset payment gateways we dont want if total is 0 (free order)
function payment_gateway_enable_check( $available_gateways ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    if ( $woocommerce->cart->total == 0 ) {
        unset($available_gateways['cod']);
        unset($available_gateways['bacs']);
    }
        return $available_gateways;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'payment_gateway_enable_check' );
```